# how to split function based on operators which are out side square brackets not inside

Tags: javascript, angular, regex

I'm new to UI, I have a requirement for my angular application, where I want to split my string to array. For example if my string is like this:

```
formula = "[ Calculation ]+[ test ]-123/LP[ Test Group MFP ]+[ Metrics1 ]*2444-76"
```

then this split function with regEx to split string on operators separators works:

```
this.formula = this.formula.split(/([+*\/-])/);
```

and gives output as below, which is fine and correct:

```
["[ Calculation ]" , "+" , "[ test ]" , "-" , "123" , "/" , "LP[ Test Group MFP ]" , "+" ,"[ Metrics1 ]" , "*" , "2444" , "-" , "76"]
```

but there is a problem with it, if my string is like below (if operator inside square brackets):

```
formula = "[ Calculation ]+[ m-4 ]-123
```

then my current split function will give output as below,

```
["[ Calculation ]" , "+" , "[ m" , "-" ,"4 ]" , "-" , "123"]
```

but my expected output is:

```
["[ Calculation ]" , "+" , "[ m-4 ]" , "-" , "123"]
```

how can I achieve this, how to split function based on operators which are not inside the square brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it by traversing the string and use flag for square brackets. I assume there is always a closing bracket.

```js
a = "[ Calculation ]+[ m-4 ]-123";

let flag = false;
let ret = [];
let str = "";
for (let i = 0, l = a.length; i < l; i++) {
  let c = a.charAt(i);
  if (c === "[" || c === "]") flag = !flag;
  if (!flag && (c === "+" || c === "-" || c === "*" || c === "/")) {
    ret.push(str);
    ret.push(c);
    str = "";
  } else {
    str += c;
  }
}
if(str.length > 0) {
  ret.push(str);
}

console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (I am writing in Python since i do not know JavaScript, but regex should be same)

**Note** This will work only when the '-' sign has one letter & one space before it (negative look behind does not allow 'non-fixed width'), so, it the 2nd square bracket has 'mm-4' for example it will not work.

```
formula = "[ Calculation ]+[ m-4 ]-123"
re.split('(?<!\[ .)([+*\/-])',formula)
```

[regex_demo](https://regex101.com/r/GPOJqn/3)

**output**

```
['[ Calculation ]', '+', '[ m-4 ]', '-', '123']
```